# Symfony2 JMSSerializerBundle expose property in YML

Tags: symfony, configuration-files, jmsserializerbundle

I want to expose only a few properties of my User class, using JMSSerializerBundle and FOSRestBundle.
It seems like the serializer bundle is not reading my configuration file.

My User class is in `src/AppBundle/Entity/User` and it extends the FOSUserBundle user class.

Here is my User class:

```
  <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="backoffice_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=70)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=70)
     */
    private $firstname;
}
```

This is my app/config.yml file

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        debug: true
        auto_detection: true
```

And the yml mappgin file in `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml` :

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    exclude: true
    properties:
        email:
            exclude: true
            expose: true
```

The file is not read (or at least not taken into account), because my API returns me all fields of my entity.

Am I forgetting something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mapping file is not loaded, because the serializer applies the rules to the class where the properties are defined. In your case - that is `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`. What you need is to override the `Third-Party Metadata` - a brief sample can be seen in bundle's [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration#overriding-third-party-metadata)

In your config.yml, `jms_serializer` should probably look like this:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

Inside directory `serializer` you should have a file named `Model.User.yml` with configuration like this:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    # add your desired configuration below.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it :) I need to configure it for the child property such as "lastname", I guess I have to  do it in the Entity.User.yml file this time

Comment: After you make the changes, remember to clear the Symfony cache, app/cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

In `JMSSerializer` you need to have one file for each class of the hierarchy.

So, the exclusion policy only apply to properties `id`, `lastname` and `firstname`; for `BaseUser` it use the default rule, which is to include everything.

To override a configuration file from another bundle, you first need to setup the folder for the namespace in the configuration with:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "%kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB"
```

And add the serializer config file in `app/serializer/FOSUB/Model.User.yml`. See the [official docs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration) for other configurations option.